# Libc6 problem in Ubuntu Mate 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-mate

I have updated ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04

apt says that the version of  package libc6 is 2.33, but in folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  there is only libc-2.32.so.

I have tried to reinstall with apt, then manually with dpkg but I obtained no results.

The problem is that some programs do not work (i.e. R) because they explicitely request version 2.33 of libc6.

What can I do?

Comment: What does `dpkg -L libc6:amd64 | grep libc-` show?

Comment: output: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so/usr/share/doc/libc6`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.gz`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/README.Debian.gz`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/README.hesiod.gz`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/changelog.Debian.gz`
`/usr/share/doc/libc6/copyright`
`/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libc6`
`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`
I have also this for `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 298 mar 31 15:44 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.solrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 dic 19  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.32.so`

Comment: It seems I have libc6 2.32 in /usr/lib/ AND libc6 2.33 in /lib